# Rails, How to show all product by category search feature?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, associations, one-to-many

Now I want to add some add search feature to my project. I have 2 table about product and category, then i'm using one to many relation. I get stuck when i want to search my product by their categories. Here my code:

**products_controller.rb:**

```
def index
  @product = Product.all
  render json: @product, status: :ok 
end

def search    
 @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
 @product = @category.products

 render json: @product, status: :ok
end

def show
  render json: @product, status: :ok
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do  
namespace :v1 do 

  resources :products
  resources :categories


  post 'products/search', to: "products#search"
  get 'products/search', to: "products#search"

  end
end
```

model **category.rb**

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :products
end
```

model **product.rb**

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
end
```

**my product table field**

```
  t.integer :category_id
  t.string :product_name
  t.string :company
  t.text   :description
  t.string :logo_img
  t.string :web_link
```

**my table category field**

```
  t.string :category_name
  t.string :status
```

How should it work for category show all their products?
Thanks for your help

Comment: `@product = @category.products` will define `@product` as a list of all the products for the category. It would be better named `@products` since it's more accurate. What specifically doesn't work about your code?

Comment: I would also take into consideration using an indexing service like solr. I understand you are pretty new to rails but it is a great tool if you want to work in RoR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add your categories_controller.rb like following
    categories_controller.rb
      def show
        category = Category.find(params[:id])
        render json: category.products, status: :ok
      end
    end

and visit `/categories/:id` url

Comment: Thanks it's help me, the problem can be solved by joining table.